# Android App Development: How to get Google Gmail account credentials to send email without user intervention

Tags: android, gmail, accountmanager

I'm trying to create an android Application, that send email automatically

I dont want user to enters gmail or password, that use default gmail account in his android device to send email automatically...
if there is any full example or any thing help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, sorry. You can use `ACTION_SEND` and `ACTION_SENDTO` to send emails without account credentials, but that requires user intervention. Or, you can use JavaMail to send email without user intervention, but then you will need all of the SMTP server information and email account credentials.